# Sorting sequence of multi-dimensional array cross-browser-compatible and with "natural case"

Tags: javascript, sorting, multidimensional-array, cross-browser, natural-sort

I need to sophistically sort somewhat large arrays (1000-2000 keys) for my web application. I got it a bit working in Safari 12.0/FF 66.0, but chrome 74.0 seems to do something else entirely.

The sequence I want to sort - case-insensitive, with natural case:

```
1. "scene"  
2. "shot"  
3. "take"  
4. "name"
```

Each of these values can be strings (eg. `4`, `4b` or `4-PU üöä!"`) or 'undefined', and may look like:

```
[
  {"scene": "1", "shot": "1", "take": "4", "name": "A031C006_170718_R1W0"},
  {"scene": "8", "shot": "8", "take": "4", "name": "A020C004_170716_R1W0"},
  {"scene": "1", "shot": "1", "take": "10", "name": "A031C013_170718_R1W0"},
  {"scene": undefined, "shot": undefined, "take": undefined, "name": "A001C549_190226_R04Q"},
  {"scene": "2", "shot": "2", "take": "1", "name": "A008C010_170715_R1W0"},
  {"scene": "5", "shot": "5", "take": "1", "name": "A015C005_170716_R1W0"},
  {"scene": "3", "shot": "3", "take": "7", "name": "A002C003_170714_R1W0"},
  {"scene": "5", "shot": "5", "take": "5", "name": "A021C005_170716_R1W0"},
  {"scene": "5", "shot": "5", "take": "9", "name": "A024C006_170717_R1W0"},
  {"scene": "1", "shot": "1", "take": "3", "name": "A004C006_170714_R1W0"},
  {"scene": "1-b", "shot": "1", "take": "3", "name": "A004C007_170718_R1W0*"},
  {"scene": "5", "shot": "5PU", "take": "6", "name": "A021C005_170716_R1W0*"},
]
```

If key `scene` does not exist, sort to the end and sort by "name".

This is part of a vue.js project and i hope to get it done without an additional library.

Here's my function so far. I use `localCompare()` to compare eg. `4a` to `4` or `4ä`. I'm pretty sure this is very slow and can be a lot better!

```
sortedFiles = sortClips(files)

sortClips(clips) {
  let firstBy=(function(){function e(f){f.thenBy=t;return f}function t(y,x){x=this;return e(function(a,b){return x(a,b)||y(a,b)})}return e})();

  let options = {
    numeric: true,
    sensitivity: 'base',
    ignorePunctuation: true
  };

  clips.sort(
    firstBy(function (v1, v2) {
      if (!v1.scene) {
        return v1.name.localeCompare(v2.name, undefined, options);
      }
      return v1.scene.localeCompare(v2.scene, undefined, options);
    })
      .thenBy(function (v1, v2) {
        if (!v1.shot) return -1;
        return v1.shot.localeCompare(v2.shot, undefined, options);
      })
      .thenBy(function (v1, v2) {
        if (!v1.take) return -1;
        return v1.take.localeCompare(v2.take, undefined, options);
      })
  );
  return clips;
},
```

Original data (scene, shot, take, name):

```
1 1 4 A031C006_170718_R1W0
8 8 4 A020C004_170716_R1W0
1 1 10 A031C013_170718_R1W0
undefined undefined undefined "A001C549_190226_R04Q"
2 2 1 A008C010_170715_R1W0
5 5 1 A015C005_170716_R1W0
3 3 7 A002C003_170714_R1W0
5 5 5 A021C005_170716_R1W0
5 5 9 A024C006_170717_R1W0
1 1 3 A004C006_170714_R1W0
1-b 1 3 A004C007_170718_R1W0*
5 5PU 6 A021C005_170716_R1W0*
```

Firefox/safari sorts:

```
8 8 4 A020C004_170716_R1W0 
1 1 4 A031C006_170718_R1W0 
1 1 10 A031C013_170718_R1W0 
undefined undefined undefined A001C549_190226_R04Q 
5 5 1 A015C005_170716_R1W0 
5 5 9 A024C006_170717_R1W0 
3 3 7 A002C003_170714_R1W0 
5 5 5 A021C005_170716_R1W0 
1 1 3 A004C006_170714_R1W0 
2 2 1 A008C010_170715_R1W0
1-b 1 3 A004C007_170718_R1W0*
5 5PU 6 A021C005_170716_R1W0*
```

Chrome sorts differently:

```
5 5 1 A015C005_170716_R1W0
5 5 9 A024C006_170717_R1W0
3 3 7 A002C003_170714_R1W0
5 5 5 A021C005_170716_R1W0
1 1 3 A004C006_170714_R1W0
undefined undefined undefined "A001C549_190226_R04Q"
8 8 4 A020C004_170716_R1W0
1 1 4 A031C006_170718_R1W0
1 1 10 A031C013_170718_R1W0
2 2 1 A008C010_170715_R1W0
1-b 1 3 A004C007_170718_R1W0*
5 5PU 6 A021C005_170716_R1W0*
```

Target:

```
1 1 3 A004C006_170714_R1W0 
1 1 4 A031C006_170718_R1W0 
1 1 10 A031C013_170718_R1W0 
1-b 1 3 A004C007_170718_R1W0*  
2 2 1 A008C010_170715_R1W0
3 3 7 A002C003_170714_R1W0 
5 5 1 A015C005_170716_R1W0 
5 5 5 A021C005_170716_R1W0 
5 5PU 6 A021C005_170716_R1W0*
5 5 9 A024C006_170717_R1W0 
8 8 4 A020C004_170716_R1W0 
undefined undefined undefined A001C549_190226_R04Q
```

How can i sort that like i want?

**UPDATE:**
I've included edge-cases:

- Scene "1-b" the added characters "-b" should be sorted after all elements with scene "1" when key is "scene".
- Shot "5PU" the added characters "PU" should be ignored when key is "shot" or "take".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an array of keys for sorting and take another key as long as the result of comparing is zero.

```js
var options = { numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base', ignorePunctuation: true },
    array = [{ scene: "1", shot: "1", take: "4", namw: "A031C006_170718_R1W0" }, { scene: "8", shot: "8", take: "4", name: "A020C004_170716_R1W0" }, { scene: "1", shot: "1", take: "10", name: "A031C013_170718_R1W0" }, { scene: undefined, shot: undefined, take: undefined, name: "A001C549_190226_R04Q" }, { scene: "2", shot: "2", take: "1", name: "A008C010_170715_R1W0" }, { scene: "5", shot: "5", take: "1", name: "A015C005_170716_R1W0" }, { scene: "3", shot: "3", take: "7", name: "A002C003_170714_R1W0" }, { scene: "5", shot: "5", take: "5", name: "A021C005_170716_R1W0" }, { scene: "5", shot: "5", take: "9", name: "A024C006_170717_R1W0" }, { scene: "1", shot: "1", take: "3", name: "A004C006_170714_R1W0" }, { scene: "1-b", shot: "1", take: "3", name: "A004C007_170718_R1W0*" }, { scene: "5", shot: "5PU", take: "6", name: "A021C005_170716_R1W0*" }],
    keys = ["scene", "shot", "take", "name"];

array.sort((a, b) => {
    var result;
    keys.some(k => result = String(a[k]).localeCompare(b[k], undefined, options));
    return result;
});
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: That works almost perfectly! Thanks! Only thing is that an array element with only "name" defined would be at the start instead of the end, right? And isn't there a possibility that "result" is `null`?

Comment: I just realized i missed some edge-cases. I've updated my question with scene "1-b" and shot "5-PU" which get sorted to the end of the array. Do you have an idea for that?

Comment: i get a different result. `'5PU'` comes after `'5'`, as `'5'` is shorter.

Comment: Thats correct, but my use case needs this sorting, basically ignoring the letters when handling key "shot" and "take":  
`5 5 1 / 5 5 5 / 5 5PU 6 / 5 5 9`
But with key "scenes" `a-b`, move to the end of all scenes `1`, *before* scene `2`:
`1 1 4 / 1 1 10 / 1-b 1 3 / 2 2 1`

Comment: the problem is, you can not switch off (randomly?) some letters, because you need then some more rules to clean up values.

Answer (score 0):

Your sort functions are not stable.

```
  if (!v1.shot) return -1;
```

What if `v2` does not have a "shot" propeprty either? Your sort function should always return the opposite result for `sort(a, b)` and `sort(b, a)`, yours does not. As Chrome seems to use another sort oder, it fails only for this browser (by now, the algorithms may change in the future).

Comment: That is indeed true! Thanks for this insight, helps me think about this case.

Answer (score 0):

This is complex question. First, the code, then the explanations:

```js
const scenes = [
  {"scene": "1", "shot": "1", "take": "4", "name": "A031C006_170718_R1W0"},
  {"scene": "8", "shot": "8", "take": "4", "name": "A020C004_170716_R1W0"},
  {"scene": "1", "shot": "1", "take": "10", "name": "A031C013_170718_R1W0"},
  {"scene": undefined, "shot": undefined, "take": undefined, "name": "A001C549_190226_R04Q"},
  {"scene": "2", "shot": "2", "take": "1", "name": "A008C010_170715_R1W0"},
  {"scene": "5", "shot": "5", "take": "1", "name": "A015C005_170716_R1W0"},
  {"scene": "3", "shot": "3", "take": "7", "name": "A002C003_170714_R1W0"},
  {"scene": "5", "shot": "5", "take": "5", "name": "A021C005_170716_R1W0"},
  {"scene": "5", "shot": "5", "take": "9", "name": "A024C006_170717_R1W0"},
  {"scene": "1", "shot": "1", "take": "3", "name": "A004C006_170714_R1W0"},
]

const compareString = (a, b) => {
  if (`${a}` !== a) return 1
  if (`${b}` !== b) return -1
  return a.localeCompare(b, undefined, {
    numeric: true,
    sensitivity: 'base',
    ignorePunctuation: true
  })
}

const sorts = [
  'scene',
  'shot',
  'take',
  'name',
]

const globalCompare = (a, b) =>
  sorts.reduce((acc, key) => {
    if (acc == 0) return compareString(a[key], b[key])
    return acc
  }, 0)

scenes.sort(globalCompare)

console.log(scenes)
```

**Explanations:**

1- Comparison function takes two arguments (traditionally `a` and `b`), and return an integer that defines which one should be "before" the other. The integer is as follows: `1` if `a` should be before than `b`, `-1` if it should be after and `0` if they are equivalent.

2- We need to ensure that the "second order" must only be sort **equivalent** objects! (This is why we use a `reduce()`)

Comment: Thanks you! That works also darn good. I've accepted Nina Scholz's answer for less lines of code :) But I just realized i missed some edge-cases. I've updated my question with scene "1-b" and shot "5-PU" which get sorted to the end of the array. Do you have an idea for that?